# How to determine a process inside a docker container is run compelety programmatically

Tags: docker

I init a docker container as my compile env, now I just want to know how to determine if the entry code is run completely, then I can do another thing...

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - Please edit your question and add `Dockerfile`, `docker run` commands you're using and a brief explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if that is what you are asking about but when command pointed in [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) or [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) ends the docker container will stop.

To list running containers use:

`docker ps`

To list all containers (including stopped) use:

`docker ps -a`

Comment: ...and if you run `docker run` without the `-d` option, the command won't return until the container has exited, which means its main process has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in the container with [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/).

To use this you should support something in your code to determine that your code run succesfull e.g. for python the logger library (or simpler: print-statements).